# How to change date format in date picker for SSRS fetchXML reports for MSCRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

How to change date format in date picker  for SSRS fetchXML reports for MSCRM 2011?

By default it is setting date picker format to mm/dd/yyyy. I want to change to dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: We have this problem for custom out of the box report also. For any report (fetch xml or out of box custom report) the date picker is always selecting the date with format mm/dd/yyyy. But we want dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this problem with Microsoft. This is a Microsoft Bug. Microsoft would fix this bug in future rollups of MSCRM 2011.

Comment: Is this fix with CRM 2011 RU 18? i am using crm 2011 ru 18 and SSRS with SQL report and still we have this issue